# How to assign values to variables by key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, forms, variables

I have a JSON string as follows: `{firstname: "foo", lastname: "bar", message: "I'm fubar" }`
and want to assign each value to a variable named exactly the same as its respective key:

I should get a `var firstname` or object `obj.firstname` to be assigned the value "foo", etc...

The list of items should obviously be extended, so I don't want to hardcode the keys/variable names to assign each value.

What would be a good way to go about this very simple task?

Does there exist a getElementById kind of solution to assign the variable identified by key with its respective value?

This is what I'm trying, with some pseudo code:

```
var firstname = "";
var lastname = "";
// etc...
var data = JSON.parse({firstname: "foo", lastname: "bar", message: "I'm fubar", age: "etc..."});

    for (var key in data) {

        ("the variable currently identified by the value of key").val(data[key]);
        // or any other way of assigning "foo" to firstname

        console.log("firstname: " + firstname + ", lastname: " + lastname);
    }
```

Which then prints

```
firstname: foo, lastname: bar
```

Comment: you can access it by `data.key` like `data.firstname`

Comment: Problem solved. I chose the object based approach because it fitted my problem best, but the other answers work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to assign it to an object which has those values as properties just use the following:

```
var obj = {firstname: "foo", lastname: "bar", message: "I'm fubar", age: "etc..."};
```

As JSON is `JavaScript Object Notation` JavaScript is able to interpret such data as JavaScript objects. Which allows you to access the properties in the way `obj.firstname` etc..

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, this simplifies everything :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you're running your code at top-level scope you're assigning variables to the window object.

```
for (var key in data) {
    this[key] = data[key]; // Equivalent to window[key] here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to define the scope into which you want to "extract" the keys. In this case, it seems that you might want to reference the global scope:

```
for (var key in data) {
    window[key] = data[key];
}
```